# How to create data in database Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a database like this in Rails :

file schema.rb

```
create_table "four_seasons", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "channel"
    t.integer  "data"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

How can I create data like : channel 1 channel 2 .... channel 89?
How can I reset id after deleting data?
Thank for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about seed?

Some useful links:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html

Comment: I know how to create 1 data but I want to create it 89 times with channel increase automatically